# How to integrate user type in to firestore authed user?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am tiring to add user type to a user when creating a user in my app depending on each case ?
will this require a cloud function or can I do it right on the fly in frontend when doing the signup ?
for example I want a user to be a client... and depending on this I will write my logic.

```js
 const Signin = (email: string, password: string) => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const { user, "USERTYPE" } = userCredential;

        if (!user.emailVerified) {
          _miscContext.SetSnackBarMsg(true, 'Please verify your email');
          return;
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this in your client-side code, a user can pick any type they want.

If that is what you want, then it's fine to do this in client-side code.

Otherwise, you'll want to set the user type from a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

Comment: how to inject it in to the user then ? in my case there is no issue since rules are set based on auth not on type.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? Are you asking how to mark a Firebase **Authentication** user as a specific type? Because that isn't possible: Firebase Auth only tracks authentication (so "is this user who they say they are?") and not authorization (so "is this user allowed to do what they are trying to do?").

Comment: I mean can I mark each user with his type ? admin , client  for example ? and when signing in I can retrieve the type ?

Comment: if not well how custom claims work ? I think I am mixing 2 concepts sorry for that.

Comment: Custom claims can only be set from a trusted environment. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims